# Connecting with computers outside the local network in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip

I found some basic examples online about sending messages between computers in Java. However i realized that i only used local ip addresses so i could only send messages to a pc connected in the same network. I rewrote most of the code to make a slightly better version but if i wanted to send a message to a computer in a different network, connected to the internet, would switching the local ip with the receiving computer's public ip address in the code do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should work, however it's common place to connect to the Internet via a modem, which in term is the device holding the public IP. Some NAT and likely port forwarding would be needed at the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To give a short answer : **yes**, as long as the receiving computer has a public address and there is no proxies blocking requests.